# Can't assign address of struct to a variable whose type is a typedef of pointer to that struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, gcc-warning

I'm somewhat new to C, I'm learning it at uni, and I think I might be misunderstanding something about typedefs. Here's my code:

```
struct stackNode
{
    char data;
    struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};
typedef struct stackNode StackNode;
typedef struct StackNode *StackNodePtr;

int main()
{
    StackNode stack;
    StackNodePtr stackPtr = &stack;
}
```

This gives me this warning:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     StackNodePtr stackPtr = &stack;
                             ^
```

However if I replace that line with this:

```
StackNode *stackPtr = &stack;
```

It works fine.

Unfortunately I'm not seeing the real difference here. Isn't `typedef struct StackNode *StackNodePtr;` just a sort of "wrapper type" for a pointer to the Stack struct? I've got a pretty good grasp of pointers and structs, but I don't know what's going on here. I'm sure I'm just missing something small.

By the way, I'm compiling in c89 mode using gcc.

Comment: Start with removing the `typedef`ing pointers. They are just harmful by obfuscating your code, hiding the semantics and eventually result in confusion - QED.

Comment: And `typedef`s are actually aliases. C is not typed by name, but by compatible/"real" type.

Comment: `typedef struct StackNode` typo as `typedef struct stackNode` (S and s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is this type definition:

```
typedef struct StackNode *StackNodePtr;
```

There is no `struct StackNode`. Only `struct stackNode` and `StackNode` exist. So you'll need to use either one of those in the typedef.

But better solution is to not hide pointers behind typedef at all:

1. It makes the pointer more clearly visible.
2. It works better with type qualifiers, such as `const` and `volatile`.  If you define `StackNodePtr`, you may have to define `ConstStackNodePtr`, `VolatileStackNodePtr` and `ConstVolatileStackNodePtr` also.

So, get rid of `StackNodePtr` and simply use the method you already tried:

```
StackNode *stackPtr = &stack;  // stackPtr is clearly a pointer
```

Comment: *But better solution is to not hide pointers behind typedef at all* Unless you are Microsoft. Then you can do that willy-nilly. Sorry, couldn't resist :) :)

Comment: The reason I'm using typedefs is because I'm doing an assignment and we're given these typedefs that we need to use. This is probably to make sure we understand how to use them, rather than to show us good practice. Thanks for pointing that out though, I will be sure to reduce hiding pointers since I can see how it would be harmful. Anyway your solution worked, indeed looking back I now see that the pointer type definition they gave us didn't actually have the struct keyword and for some reason I wrote it anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"stackNode" is misspelled in

```
typedef struct StackNode *StackNodePtr;
```

(capital "S").